# TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class

Tags: python, typeerror, abstract-class, can-bus, uds

I try to run code to send a UDS extended diagnostics request on CAN

```py
from uds import Uds

PCM = Uds(resId=0x200, reqId=0x250, transportProtocol="CAN", interface="vector", channel="0", appName="CANoe")
response = PCM.send([0x10, 0x03])
```

But I get following Type error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\__work__\Karol_projects\main.py", line 26, in <module>
    PCM = Uds(resId=0x200, reqId=0x250, transportProtocol="CAN", interface="vector", channel="0", appName="CANoe")
  File "C:\__work__\Karol_projects\venv\lib\site-packages\uds\uds_communications\Uds\Uds.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.tp = tpFactory(self.__transportProtocol, configPath=configPath, **kwargs)
  File "C:\__work__\Karol_projects\venv\lib\site-packages\uds\uds_communications\TransportProtocols\TpFactory.py", line 37, in __call__
    return CanTp(configPath=configPath, **kwargs)
  File "C:\__work__\Karol_projects\venv\lib\site-packages\uds\uds_communications\TransportProtocols\Can\CanTp.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.__connection = canConnectionFactory(self.callback_onReceive,
  File "C:\__work__\Karol_projects\venv\lib\site-packages\uds\uds_communications\TransportProtocols\Can\CanConnectionFactory.py", line 52, in __call__
    CanConnectionFactory.connections[connectionKey] = CanConnection(callback, filter,
  File "C:\__work__\Karol_projects\venv\lib\site-packages\uds\uds_communications\TransportProtocols\Can\CanConnection.py", line 21, in __init__
    listener = can.Listener()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Listener with abstract method on_message_received
```

I have seen similar posts but anyway I can't get a proper solution. I only imported python-can and python-uds modules and had tried to send a can message. I don't have much experience with OOP especially with abstract classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python-uds` is an older library, and hasn't seen new releases in 3 and half years now ([version 1.0.2 was released in March 2019](https://pypi.org/project/python-uds/#history)). `python-can` on the other hand, has made major strides in that time, and released a major update, [version 4.0.0 in February 2022](https://github.com/hardbyte/python-can/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md). That release is fundamentally incompatible with `python-uds`, causing the traceback you see.

You have two options:

- Downgrade `python-can`; when `python-uds` was last released, `python-can` had released version 3.1.1, but it may be that later 3.x.x versions also work. See the [`python-can` release page on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/python-can/#history) for the full list.  You could try reading the [`python-can` changelog](https://github.com/hardbyte/python-can/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md) to see if something stands out if the last 3.x release, `3.3.4`, doesn't work but `3.1.1` does to see what the latest version that works would be. Or, just bisect the versions between 3.3.4 and 3.1.1 until you find the last compatible release.
- Switch to a different Uds library. The [`py-uds` project](https://pypi.org/project/py-uds/) has seen more recent releases (version 0.2.0 was released in  December last year and their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mdabrowski1990/uds) shows active development continued up to February 2022 at least.

Comment: I have downgraded python-can version to 3.3.4 and it seems to work fine. Thank You for fast answer